# Can I get a C# Visual studio program to control a raspberry pi?

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio, raspberry-pi

I am working on a project that combines a visual studio application and a raspberry pi.

Is there an easy way to run a terminal program (like "python script.py") on a raspberry pi through a C# Visual Studio Program and retrieve the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**IF YOU RUN Windows 10 ON YOUR Raspberry** .

You can use a remote Powershell on a Raspberry running Windows 10 with the following :

```
# Start WinRM on the local Windows OS
net start WinRM

# Vérify RaspBerry PI3 access
Test-Connection jpbraspbpi3-1

# Allow accesss to Raspberry PI3
Set-Item WSMan:\localhost\Client\TrustedHosts -Value 'jpbraspbpi3-1'

# Etablish the connexion
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 'jpbraspbpi3-1' -Credential (Get-Credential -UserName 'administrator' -Message 'Mot de passe !')

# You can allow a pseudo cmd.exe command line on the Windows 10 of your Raspberry
reg.exe ADD "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\EmbeddedMode\ProcessLauncher" /v AllowedExecutableFilesList /t REG_MULTI_SZ /d "c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe\0"
```

Then you can use developp using [.NET core on Raspberry](https://github.com/dotnet/core/blob/master/samples/RaspberryPiInstructions.md).

**IF YOUR RUN RASPBIAN**, you can [deploy Mono](http://www.raspberry-sharp.org/eric-bezine/2012/10/mono-framework/installing-mono-raspberry-pi/) and develop with visual studio or visual Code (.net core).

Comment: I would say yes, but I don't test it. If you test it be careful to use a PowerShell  version 5.0 or upper.